# Outdated and broken libpam-radius-auth package version in Ubuntu 22.04.x

Tags: package-management, authentication, radius

The Ubuntu 22.04.x version of libpam is not working correctly for me. It does not allow user authentication with an active directory.
I have installed the package in its latest version, downloading the source code and compiling it and it works perfectly.

The version of libpam-radius-auth package that comes in Ubuntu 22.04.x is 2.0.0-1, while the latest one is 2.0.1 and this one works fine.

Why Ubuntu in its latest version has 2.0.0-1 and not 2.0.1?

When are you going to release libpam-radius-auth 2.0.1 on Ubuntu 22.04.x?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what the Debian Package tracker has to say on the subject:

https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/libpam-radius-auth

[image]

This tells us three facts:

1. Debian is correctly tracking that a new version is available.
2. Some basic maintenance work needs to happen.
3. The last action occurred two years ago.

Keeping in mind that Debian is 100% volunteer, these facts suggest that the current maintainer could use some assistance.

- "Assistance" means real help from another volunteer. It does NOT mean reminders or complaints or demands.

Once updated for Debian, the updated source code will merge into a future release of Ubuntu automatically.

- Older releases of Ubuntu will NOT get the new version unless there is an exceptional circumstance.

Folks who want to help, and want to learn the packaging process, should start their journey at http://mentors.debian.net.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply.

I already knew that Debian is more conservative with package versions, and that Ubuntu is a Debian derivative, as you I have been in Linux since the kernels were compiled.

I thought Ubuntu went a step further and offered more current versions.

Reading your answer I don't know if this last one is true, since I think it is something fundamental in Ubuntu, otherwise why do we want Ubuntu in servers having Debian?

Best Regards.

Comment: Ubuntu has always merged most deb packages from Debian. As an alternative, Ubuntu volunteers are welcome to build updated packages (and ask a MOTU) to upload them to Ubuntu, but few volunteers have stepped forward to do that. Canonical engineers can also build updates for specific packages (like web browsers), but that lane is very narrow.